# Abstract control with value from outside angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when i open dialog on angular material i send some data to the dialog

so on the dialog component
i create custom validation for the checking if the value is over or lower but i keep getting an error that the properties is undefined

here is my code

```
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: VendorDataMaster,
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  public usd: UserdetailsService ) { }

this.validateFormVendor = this.fb.group({
      InvoiceAmountcontrol: [ this.data.InvoiceAmount , [ Validators.required, this.ToleranceValidator] ],
      NoInvoicecontrol: [ this.data.NoInvoice, [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateInvoicecontrol: [ this.data.DateInvoice, [ Validators.required ] ],
      NoFakturPajakcontrol: [ this.data.NoFakturPajak, [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateFakturPajakcontrol: [ this.data.DateFakturPajak, [ Validators.required ] ],
      Statuscontrol : [ {value:this.data.StatusInv, disabled: true} ]
    });
  }
  ToleranceValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
// this is when the data is undifiend
      console.log(this.data.AmountGR)
      if (parseInt(control.value) >  parseInt(this.data.AmountGR) * 1) {
        return { ToleranceRange : true };
      }
      return null;
  }
  public hasError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) =>{
    return this.validateFormVendor.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }
```

i guess the ngif is start faster than the constractor but i got no clue what happen

ive try using try catch but doesnot solve the issue,
and also i put the result on exported component so that i can use it on dialog component but still undefiend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `ToleranceValidator` as a `async` validator, like below. instead of adding it in the second value of the array, add it in the third place.

```
this.validateFormVendor = this.fb.group({
      InvoiceAmountcontrol: [ this.data.InvoiceAmount , [ Validators.required], this.ToleranceValidator ],
      NoInvoicecontrol: [ this.data.NoInvoice, [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateInvoicecontrol: [ this.data.DateInvoice, [ Validators.required ] ],
      NoFakturPajakcontrol: [ this.data.NoFakturPajak, [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateFakturPajakcontrol: [ this.data.DateFakturPajak, [ Validators.required ] ],
      Statuscontrol : [ {value:this.data.StatusInv, disabled: true} ]
    });
  }
```

Comment: when i input text to the input field its still show error on data undefined, i guess the value of data still not being patch, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Use bind

```
this.validateFormVendor = this.fb.group({
      InvoiceAmountcontrol: [ '' , [ Validators.required, this.ToleranceValidator.bind(this)] ],
      NoInvoicecontrol: ['', [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateInvoicecontrol: [ '', [ Validators.required ] ],
      NoFakturPajakcontrol: [ '', [ Validators.required ] ],
      DateFakturPajakcontrol: [ '', [ Validators.required ] ],
      Statuscontrol : [ {value:'', disabled: true} ]
    });
  }
```